# __dopostback is not working in javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net

am calling `__dopostback` function in javascript while closing event of browser but its not working in Chrome.

the same function is working in IE

can any one give me the solution.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"> 
function doUnload() 
{ 
 var btnlogout = document.getElementById("ctl00_lbtn_Logout"); alert(btnlogout);   
 __doPostBack(btnlogout, ''); 
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing a __doPostBack, you need to pass the control's UniqueID via javascript. ClientID will not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be passing the `btnlogout` id as string (not sure if you have to remove the `ctl00` thing since it's a child control) as the function expects text and it is probably resolved during the request on the server..

Take a look at this article: 
http://wiki.asp.net/page.aspx/1082/dopostback-function/

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
btnlogout.click();
```

since you already have a reference to the button and, by the way, don't get the element the way you are doing it; do this instead:

```
var btnlogout = document.getElementById("<%=btn_Logout.ClientID%>");
```

Comment: Am getting this error if i use code blocks. "The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>)."

Answer (score 0):

Please try to `getElementById` this way

```
var btnlogout = document.getElementById('<%= lbtn_Logout.ClientID %>'); 
alert(btnlogout)
```

and test it again , it will work..

Answer (score 0):

dopostback(clientID, args)'s first parameter must be a control's clientid, it is a string , not object (of course string is object ) ..
in your case , i assume that is 'ctl00_lbtn_Logout', pass the right params like :

```
__doPostBack('<%= downloadUp.ClientID %>', current_index);
```

if your control is server side control, change 'downloadUp' to your control's id  , else you just need pass the id